# How to group by multiple keys at the same time using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This works, but I was wondering if there was a better way than creating a string with `a` and `b` and later splitting it:

```
const data = [
    { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40 },
    { a: 10, b: 20, c: 31, d: 41 },
    { a: 12, b: 22, c: 32, d: 42 }
];

d3.rollups(
    data,
    x => ({
      c: x.map(d => d.c),
      d: x.map(d => d.d)
    }),
    d => `${d.a} ${d.b}`
  )
  .map(([key, values]) => {
    const [a, b] = key.split(' ');
    return {a, b, ...values};
  });

// OUTPUT
// [
//   {a: "10", b: "20", c: [30, 31], d: [40, 41]},
//   {a: "12", b: "22", c: [32], d: [42]}
// ]
```

Comment: Good question! Looking simple at first, it turns out to be quite tricky. I doubt there is a better way to use a combined key like your approach. You could do a nested rollup but then you'd have to loop through the resulting arrays to flatten them to the desired output.

Comment: Borderline duplicate of [*"Grouping objects in an array by multiple keys"*](/q/46167404). Although we might be better off closing that one as a duplicate of this question given the quality of answers. Also, hitting Google with something like "javascript group array of objects by multiple keys" yields a plethora of possible approaches, both D3 as well as VanillaJS.

Comment: Additionally, you might be interested in the performance results I posted as part of my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224118/how-to-group-by-multiple-keys-at-the-same-time-using-d3#comment117119264_66242086) on Robin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With d3 v7 released, there is now a better way to do this using the new `d3.flatRollup`.

```js
const data = [
    { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40 },
    { a: 10, b: 20, c: 31, d: 41 },
    { a: 12, b: 22, c: 32, d: 42 }
];

const result = d3.flatRollup(
    data,
    x => ({
      c: x.map(d => d.c),
      d: x.map(d => d.d)
    }),
    d => d.a,
    d => d.b
  );
console.log(result);

const flattened = result.map(([a, b, values]) => ({a, b, ...values}));
console.log(flattened);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@3.0.2/dist/d3-array.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already know [`d3.rollups()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#rollups) will create nested arrays if you have more than one key:

> If more than one key is specified, a nested Map [or array] is returned.

Therefore, as `d3.rollups` doesn't fit your needs, I believe it's easier to create a plain JavaScript function (I'm aware of *"using D3"* in your title, but even in a D3 code nothing forbids us of writing plain JS solutions where D3 has none).

In the following example I'm purposefully writing a verbose function (with comments) so each part of it is clear, avoiding more complex features which could make it substantially short (but more cryptic). In this function I'm using `reduce`, so the data array is looped only once. `myKeys` is the array of keys you'll use to rollup.

Here is the function and the comments:

```
function groupedRollup(myArray, myKeys) {
  return myArray.reduce((a, c) => {
    //Find the object in the acc with all 'myKeys' equivalent to the current
    const foundObject = a.find(e => myKeys.every(f => e[f] === c[f]));
    //if found, push the value for each key which is not in 'myKeys'
    if (foundObject) {
      for (let key in foundObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) foundObject[key].push(c[key]);
      };
    //if not found, push the current object with all non 'myKeys' keys as arrays
    } else {
      const copiedObject = Object.assign({}, c);//avoids mutation
      for (let key in copiedObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) copiedObject[key] = [copiedObject[key]];
      };
      a.push(copiedObject);
    };
    return a;
  }, [])
};
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const data = [{
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30,
    d: 40
  },
  {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 31,
    d: 41
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 22,
    c: 32,
    d: 42
  }
];
const keys = ["a", "b"];

console.log(groupedRollup(data, keys))

function groupedRollup(myArray, myKeys) {
  return myArray.reduce((a, c) => {
    const foundObject = a.find(e => myKeys.every(f => e[f] === c[f]));
    if (foundObject) {
      for (let key in foundObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) foundObject[key].push(c[key]);
      };
    } else {
      const copiedObject = Object.assign({}, c);
      for (let key in copiedObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) copiedObject[key] = [copiedObject[key]];
      };
      a.push(copiedObject);
    };
    return a;
  }, [])
};
```

And here is a demo with a more complex data:

```js
const data = [{
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30,
    d: 40,
    e: 5,
    f: 19
  },
  {
    a: 10,
    b: 55,
    c: 37,
    d: 40,
    e: 5,
    f: 19
  },
  {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 31,
    d: 48,
    e: 5,
    f: 18
  },
  {
    a: 80,
    b: 20,
    c: 31,
    d: 48,
    e: 5,
    f: 18
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 8,
    e: 5,
    f: 9
  },
  {
    a: 10,
    b: 88,
    c: 44,
    d: 33,
    e: 5,
    f: 19
  }
];
const keys = ["a", "e", "f"];

console.log(groupedRollup(data, keys))

function groupedRollup(myArray, myKeys) {
  return myArray.reduce((a, c) => {
    const foundObject = a.find(e => myKeys.every(f => e[f] === c[f]));
    if (foundObject) {
      for (let key in foundObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) foundObject[key].push(c[key]);
      };
    } else {
      const copiedObject = Object.assign({}, c);
      for (let key in copiedObject) {
        if (!keys.includes(key)) copiedObject[key] = [copiedObject[key]];
      };
      a.push(copiedObject);
    };
    return a;
  }, [])
};
```

Finally, pay attention that this function will push duplicated values (in the above example `d: [40, 40, 33]`). If that's not what you want then just check for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The approach below allows you to remove the `split`, but does not prevent the need to create a string for the compound key. In this case, using `JSON.stringify({a: d.a, b: d.b})` instead of `${d.a} ${d.b}`, allows for the `map` to return an object where the `c` and `d` properties can be assigned to the `parse` of the key.

This preserves some of the 'd3-ishness' of your question and the utility of `rollups` to deal with the creation of the arrays for `c` and `d`.

```js
const data = [
  { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40 },
  { a: 10, b: 20, c: 31, d: 41 },
  { a: 12, b: 22, c: 32, d: 42 }
];

const groups = d3.rollups(
  data,
  x => ({
    c: x.map(d => d.c),
    d: x.map(d => d.d)
  }),
  d => JSON.stringify({a: d.a, b: d.b}) // compare with `${d.a} ${d.b}`
).map(arr => Object.assign(JSON.parse(arr[0]), arr[1]));

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The approach can accommodate the extensibility of @Gerado Furtado's answer, but I fear it's getting a little hectic:

```js
const data = [
  {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40, e: 5, f: 19},
  {a: 10, b: 55, c: 37, d: 40, e: 5, f: 19},
  {a: 10, b: 20, c: 31, d: 48, e: 5, f: 18},
  {a: 80, b: 20, c: 31, d: 48, e: 5, f: 18},
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 8, e: 5, f: 9},
  {a: 10, b: 88, c: 44, d: 33, e: 5, f: 19}
];
const keys = ["a", "e", "f"];

const groupedRollup = (data, keys) => {
  const others = Object.keys(data[0])
    .filter(k => !keys.includes(k)); // finds b, c, d as not part of compound key
    
  return d3.rollups(
    data,
    x => Object.assign(
      {}, 
      ...others.map(k => {
        return {[k]: x.map(d => d[k])} // dynamically create reducer
      })
    ),
    d => JSON.stringify(
      Object.assign(
        {}, 
        ...keys.map(k => {
          return {[k]: d[k]} // dynamically add keys
        })
      )
    ) // and stringify for compound key
  ).map(arr => Object.fromEntries( // sorting the output object
    Object.entries( // keys in alpha order
      Object.assign(JSON.parse(arr[0]), arr[1])).sort() // same approach
    )
  );
}

console.log(groupedRollup(data, keys));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

There's some interesting talk about the introduction of use of [`InternMap`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/pull/185) in `rollups` and the associated functions - but I don't see either that it's ready, or that it's useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach performs even worse than the original one which is no wonder as the stringify/parse is slower than the string concatenation/split: https://jsbench.me/5akl9m19hq/1. Although, no doubt, I am a big fan of D3's I think Gerardo's no-D3 solution is the preferable one for this problem.

Comment: `InternMap`s were introduced to the main bundle as of [v6.4.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.4.0) and are already used by `d3.rollups`.